# Build JDeveloper ADF project using Maven

Tags: maven, jdeveloper

I have a project built in Jdeveloper 11.1.1.3.0. It uses ADF.
At the moment we use ANT to build the EAR for deployment.

We want to move it to Maven 3.0

My questions are

1. I do not find the ADF libraries to add as dependencies in my POM in Maven repository. I have read that I will have to add them in my local repository. Is there any easier way to get this done.
2. Will the Maven plugin for "JDeveloper Studio 11.1.1.3.0" help me build the POM for the project. I tried doing so but did not get anything useful.

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 2):

These comments refer to ADF 11g R1

There is no Maven support out of the box for JDeveloper 11g. We resort to putting Oracle jar files in our Nexus third-party repository, using the group Id com.oracle.<type>.<module name> where <type> is weblogic, common, soa, oim, adf, etc., and <module name> is the name of oracle module that contains the jar file. If the jar file is not part of a module, omit it.

Be aware that many Oracle jar files make use of manifest class paths that rely on the directory structure of the installed oracle product. Also, JDeveloper has its own application & project directory structure that is not  the same as the default Maven project structure. This makes creating a Maven POM for an ADF project more difficult than it should be.

ADF Applications are built and deployed using the Oracle ojdeploy utility (JDeveloper treats creating an ear file as another type of deployment.) For information on ojdeploy, please see [the oracle ojdeploy documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/user.1112/e17455/deploying_apps.htm). It is best to use ojdeploy because it handles the ADF framework properly.

JDeveloper documentation is available on [The Oracle OTN web site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/jdev11gr1-393658.html)
The best method we have found is to use the Maven antrun plug-in to run an ANT script.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do serious work with Maven and ADF you should be using JDeveloper/ADF 12c - where there is support for this out of the box.